# bootstrap radio button label styling

Tags: css, radio-button, styles

I try to style my bootstrap radio button as below -

label in default: transparent background and font in green color

label after click (i.e. after it is checked): green background color and font in white color

```
<div id ="trial" data-toggle="buttons">     
<label class="btn btn-success btn-outline"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="M">Male</label>
<label class="btn btn-success btn-outline"><input type="radio" name="sex" value="F">Female</label>   
</div>
```

I tried to make use of 'active' and 'focus' but it will return to default when I click somewhere else. Is there any way to keep the 'label after click' (radio button is checked) even it is clicked somewhere else.

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/muchproblem/4vmucdq7/17/

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is you are adding bootstrap.min.js file before jquery...You need to add jQuery first and then all other js files and it will work..Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Navnit, thanks for your input, I did such a mistake. It works now, thanks.

Comment: happy to help...:)